# Multiple FBX meshes with one texture file for all of them

Tags: mesh

My friend sent me one FBX file that contains 6 separated types of grass meshes and one file of textures for all of them. How do I upload these textures to the meshes without messing it up? I am kinda beginner at this.

Comment: what do you mean "upload textures to the meshes"? Textures are used by materials. You can apply the same material to any number of meshes, and it will mess nothing.

Comment: Yes, but when I import the FBX, I don't know why, but it doesn't show the textures/materials, even when I change the viewport. I have to import them manually.

Comment: the fbx importer has the checkbox "image search" which looks for images in subfolders. Just tried it in 2.76b. it works both in blender internal, and in cycles. it creates materials, and assigns images to textures. it does it a bit weird, (tpp many textures, nodes, absolute paths) but the images show up on render. Try to view the path in the fbx with text search of your image name. maybe it wants different image name that stated there.